# Does context switching works everytime, or does it result in unexpected behaviour?

Tags: c++, c, linux

In the below code my friend has stimulated a dead lock situation with context switching and mutex lock in linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
pthread_mutex_t l1, l2;
void* func1();
void* func2();

int main()
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&l1, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&l2, NULL);
    pthread_t t1, t2;
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, func1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, func2, NULL);
    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);
}

void* func1()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&l1);
    printf("\nl1 locked in func 1"); // 1
    sleep(1);
    printf("\ntrying to Lock l2 in func 1"); // 2
    pthread_mutex_lock(&l2);
}

void* func2()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&l2);
    printf("\nl2 locked in func 2"); // 3
    sleep(1);
    printf("\ntrying to Lock l1 in func 2"); // 4
    pthread_mutex_lock(&l1);
}
```

The problem is, after execution it printed Statement 1,3 and 4
But the correct output should have been statements 1,3 and 2

But when I change the value of sleep in func2 to sleep(4) It works fine.

And if I don't write statement 2 and 4, after execution statement 1 is printed, but statements 1 and 3 should be printed.

Later after changing the func2 sleep(1) to sleep(4), switching it back to sleep(1) becomes correct working state...

Is all of this unexpected behaviour or is there a reason for this to be happening...
Or a simple solution to correct all these behaviours would help me to understand.
Thanks.

Comment: The only thing I can see from your code is that 1 will come before 2 and 3 will come before 4. Nothing else is guaranteed.

Comment: You should move the `\n` at the end of the line, otherwise the stdout buffer won't be flushed and you will not see the last message before the deadlock.

Comment: @mch is there a way to flush the stdout buffer explicitly

Comment: If you want to guarantee that 1 comes before 3, then you must synchronize those statements. 3 shouldn't get run until a condition variable gets set, which would happen in `func1` after 1

Comment: Nowadays with multi-core CPUs, it is quite possible that both threads will execute _at the same time_, and not in any given sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're spawning threads there's no guarantee that the threads will start executing in the order you spawned them. Sometimes it will happen, other times not. There's no guarantee that 1 comes before 3. The only thing you're guaranteed that `func1` will be called in its own thread at any point after your call to `pthread_create` and `pthread_join` will not return until `func1` returns in that thread. Same goes for `func2`. You are definitely not guaranteed that one of the threads will start running before the other.

`sleep` is not a sufficient synchronization mechanism. `sleep` is defined to have the process wait *at least* X seconds. It's completely legal for the operating system to make your process wait for 10 times more. Unlikely, but it can happen. Especially on a busy system. Mix `sleep` and threads and anything can happen. Since it's quite likely (but definitely not guaranteed) that the threads will run very close in time to each other, and timers in your system don't have infinite precision, it's quite likely that their `sleep` will be scheduled to end at the "same time" ("same time" is a very dangerous term, but in this case it means the same tick of some timer interrupt). So the threads will be awakened together, with no guarantees which will be awakened before the other. And regardless which one gets awakened before the other there's still no telling which of those will start running first. Any luck you had with one of the threads running before the other will definitely run out here.

You're not flushing your stdout properly by having the newlines at the beginning of the printfs instead of at the end (where does this come from? so many people do this in stackoverflow questions for no reason whatsoever). Add a newline at the end of printfs and since your stdout is most likely line buffered, the printfs will flush at the end of the line.

You also have a bunch of mutexes with no apparent function other than causing a deadlock at the end.

In fact, the way the code is written, it's perfectly possible (although quite unlikely) that `func2` starts running in a thread, locks `l2`, prints and sleeps and prints again, locks `l1` and returns before any thread has started running `func1`. This will lead to `func1` not printing anything because it will hang trying to lock `l1`.

Comment: So instead of using sleep as synchronous.. Is using booleen variable more good?...or what is the best way to synchronous threads?

Comment: @sharan pthreads have many different way to synchronize things. mutexes, rwlocks, barriers, condition variables, semaphores, etc. Read up on those because it's a complex topic. A basic threads tutorial should talk about locking. A boolean won't do you much good.